# Declare array with no definite size in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I need an array of strings that contains nothing at initial declaration because I will use it as storage of strings that I will get from the users. I will do this through looping. Anybody knows how to declare an array with no definite size initially using NSArray? Thanks!

Comment: Can try for NSMutable Array.......(if you dont need to specify the size)

Comment: Read the question again, now think about the first guess that comes to your mind. Is it not `[[NSArray alloc] init]`?

Comment: `[NSMutableArray array]` if you want a mutable array as it sounds like you do.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` use `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Thanks to you all. I have read some tutorials and more about Objective-C and i found out about this `NSMutableArray` and I am now using it with my App. :) Sorry to bother you about this little problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `[[NSArray alloc] init]` and use `array = [array arrayByAddingObject:string]`
2. `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` and use `[array addObject:string]`

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're meaning `NSMutableArray`.

`NSMutableArray` can expand to hold any amount of objects (given memory limitations). Just make it the usual way: `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` and then add objects.

Every `NSMutableArray` has a initial capacity. If you exceed this amount of objects, some book-keeping happens behind the scenes to adjust for a larger capacity, but it's not something you need to do anything about.

If you know that an `NSMutableArray` is going to hold X objects, and no more, you can specify that the array has that capacity:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:X];
```

This means that no behind the scenes resizing of the array will happen at a later time. It's a performance/efficiency improvement, but you code will still work even if you don't do this.

Comment: "no behind the scenes resizing of the array will happen at a later time" -- what do you mean by this? The array will expand as necessary when you add new items.

Comment: I'm referring to the doubling-of-capacity strategy usually found when the current capacity of the mutable array is exceeded. It doesn't just increase its capacity by one each time you add a new item beyond the original capacity limit.

Answer (score 4):

NSMutableArray with no definite size,

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: -1 as this is incorrect for what the user wants. `NSArray` is not a mutable array. So when the user is looping and tries adding to the `NSArray` they can't cause a none mutable array can't add or remove objects. They need to be using an `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `NSMutableArray` which allows elements to be added and removed (i.e. *mutable*):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

or, using the [new Objective-C literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) syntax:

```
NSMutableArray *array = @[];
```